# Perl how to pass in a regular expression to my subroutine like grep

Tags: regex, perl, parameters, grep

```
print grep /test/, "mytestphrase";
```

With the grep syntax you can pass in a regular expression without quotes.
I want the same behavior for my subroutine as follows:

```
use strict; 
use warnings;

sub testsub {
    my $regex = shift;
    my $phrase = shift;

    print grep $regex, $phrase;
}

testsub /test/, "mytestphrase";
```

However it tries before the testsub call to evaluate `$_` against my regex, issuing following error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at ./a.pl line 14.
```

Is it possible to call testsub like the grep command and how must the subroutine be modified to support that?

Answer (score 5):

Pass the parameter like this:

```
testsub qr/test/, "mytestphrase";
```

Change also the utilisation of `$regex` to `/$regex/`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; 
use warnings;

sub testsub {
    my $regex = shift;
    my $phrase = shift;
    print grep /$regex/, $phrase;
}

testsub qr/test/, "mytestphrase";
```

Comment: I know that this will work, I want to understand the grep trick though. Don't get me wrong my question is: Is it possible to call testsub like the grep command and how must the subroutine be modified to support that ?

Comment: You can always use [prototypes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes), although overriding Perl's normal behaviour is not likely to win you any popularity contests.

Comment: Short clean solution, +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK there is no way to replicate grep's special "take a block OR take a bare expression" syntax.  [As pointed out in TLP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24490989/14660), you can use the `&@` prototype to get the `foo {...} LIST` syntax, but you can't ask for a block OR a scalar.

There is also no prototype to get a bare regular expression.  You must pass in a compiled regular expression, a `qr/.../`, [as noted by M42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24490546/14660).

Prototypes are incomplete.  They cannot express the full range of Perl's built in functions.  `open`, `split`, `print` and even apparently simple ones like `chomp`.  You can check this by asking for `print prototype 'CORE::some_function'`.  Some say this is a weakness in prototypes.  Some say this is a madness in Perl's built in functions.

Prototypes should only be used when you are replacing built in functions.  They are really best avoided.  One of the few valid idioms is to use the `&@` prototype to provide the `foo {...} LIST` idiom for list processing.

I would recommend you pass in `qr//` or `sub { ... }` to your function normally and pass it along to `grep`.

Did I say there's *no way* to do it?  What was I thinking, this is Perl!  If you REALLY REALLY REALLY want this feature, you can delve into [Devel::Declare](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Declare).  This module lets you come up with your own function call syntax.  To say it is not easy to use is an understatement.  Things like [Method::Signatures](https://metacpan.org/pod/Method::Signatures) and [TryCatch](https://metacpan.org/pod/TryCatch) use it to work their magic.  If you're at the level of just figuring out `qr//`, I would recommend against bringing Devel::Declare into production code.  Mess around with it, though.

Comment: He he I don't want to temper with you guys :-)
This is all valid, and it is fine with me if it is not feasible. I just want to figure that out. But don't spend time on that.

Comment: `grep`/`map` don't "take bare block or take a regular expression"; they take bare block or take an *arbitrary* expression. For example: `my @positive = grep $_>0, @numbers`. No regular expression or block there! [Params::Lazy](https://metacpan.org/pod/Params::Lazy) allows you to define a function with a `grep`/`map`-like prototype, though it's probably too immature to rely on for production code.

Answer (score 1):

If you read http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes you will find this example:

```
Declared as          Called as
...
sub mygrep (&@)      mygrep { /foo/ } $a, $b, $c
```

Which presumably is what you are referring to.

Most of the time, prototypes are not really what you want, and should not be used. Prototypes are used for the purpose of making Perl subroutines act like some of the built-in functions, like for example `grep`.

As for recommendations, I would suggest you do as M42 suggests in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24490546/725418).

Comment: Yes I do know also about prototype &@ using the block syntax, but my question is about the "normal" grep syntax: grep $regex, $phrase; and I would like to make this work - if feasible - with my subroutine: testsub /test/, "mytestphrase"; - without quotes and without block.

Comment: @user2050516 Prototypes is a narrow and obscure field of Perl programming. I don't know what the prototype for "code without a block" is, and I cannot find it on google. You are welcome to try. I assume this is purely of academic interest, since the practical solutions available (using `qr()` or `sub { ... }` or prototypes + block) are much simpler to accomplish than what you propose.

Comment: I have a question that's why I am here. My question is pretty clear and I hope you can understand I cannot and will not make my question suitable for your answer. Just leave it for someone who might know. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @user2050516 Did I ask you to change your question to suit my answer? Not quite sure what you are talking about there.

Comment: no definitely you did not ask to change the question as I did not ask to circumvent with any workaround. From a technical standpoint so far - likely somehow feasible - but also no prove.